# Are identifiers starting with an underscore reserved according to the latest C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

I'm interested in the relevant sections from the standard (if any).

Comment: For completeness I'll link here the old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier and mention that the rules did not change.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that one. Although it's relevant to ask specifically for C++11, I'm not sure what would be the appropriate course of action now. Should this one be closed and the top answer of the other edited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when the underscore is followed by another underscore or an uppercase letter (i.e. for preprocessor #defines or macros), or if the identifier is in the global namespace (§17.6.4.3.2):

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> — Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
>
> — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Note that the first point means that if two underscores appear *anywhere* in the identifier, even in the middle or at the end, the name is reserved. Also, I would add (§17.6.4.3.5, emphasis mine):

> **Literal suffix identifiers** that *do not* start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

Comment: What are literal suffix identifiers exactly? Does this mean that it's OK to use `_name` for private members?

Comment: @fish that rule pertains to user-defined literals, meaning that `foo operator"" _bar(const char*);` is ok, but `foo operator"" bar(const char*);` is reserved

Comment: @fish: It's talking about [user-defined literals.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals)

Comment: I find it important to emphasize that the double underscore rule isn't limited to just the beginning; a double underscore *anywhere* means it is reserved.

Comment: @chris yes, I kinda got that in by saying _for preprocessor #defines_, because they disregard scope.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, Well, it just took me a while before I realized that `foo__bar` was reserved, not just `__foobar`, and I've seen the same thing from quite a few others.

Comment: @chris oh, I thought you were talking about in any scope. I didn't realise you were talking about "anywhere in the identifer". That is an important point, I'll add a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

They are not reserved like `for` but you should not use them, since compiler developers may use them to name their own functions, so it may conflict with your function. So if you use `my_class::_function` then there should be no error, but write a global function like `void _function()` may generate a duplicate with one compiler!

Comment: While, true in the case you provided, macros ignore scope, so having a member function called `foo__bar` or `_FooBar` can still collide with those.