# Using sizeof operator on a typedef-ed struct

Tags: c++, typedef

This might be something too obvious. However, I couldn't find the specific answer though many stackoverflow threads talk about different aspects of this.

```
typedef struct _tmp {
   unsigned int a;
   unsigned int b;
} tmp;

int main()
{
    int c=10;
    if (c <= sizeof tmp) {
       printf("less\n");
    } else {
       printf("more\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this prog as -

```
g++ -lstdc++ a.cpp
```

I get an error -

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

I think I am missing something very obvious and straightforward. But can't seem to pinpoint it :-/

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check out this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12924243/596167.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### 5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]

> 1) The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is
>   either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), **or a parenthesized *type-id*.** (emphasis mine)

In your case, it is a *type-id* so it must be parenthesized. What a type-id is is described in **8.1 Type names [dcl.name]**.

`sizeof tmp` should be `sizeof (tmp)`.

As in

`if (c <= sizeof tmp)` should be `if (c <= sizeof (tmp))`.

Yup, pretty "obvious and straightforward".

Answer (score 11):

The sizeof operator have two forms:

```
sizeof expression
sizeof(type)
```

As you're giving it a type, you need the parenthesis, `sizeof(tmp)`

Comment: but the recommended form is sizeof(type)

Comment: @MarwenBkh That's quite subjective. I recommend you don't use the parenthesis when it's not needed, others might make other recommendations.

Comment: Syntax of sizeof : sizeof( parameter_pack )  (since C++11)

Comment: @MarwenBkh Can you clarify what you are saying ? Are you saying that C++ 11 only allows sizeof with parenthesis ? That is incorrect. C++11 introduced a third syntax for sizeof though, `sizeof..( parameter_pack )` (note that the three ... are part of the syntax too)

Answer (score 3):

add parentheses around `tmp`: `sizeof(tmp)`