# List of (names of) functions that are specially recognized by C++. (e.g. operator++,begin)

Tags: c++, operators, language-lawyer, non-member-functions

I have just learned C++ for a little bit, and discover some special functions.

**Example 1**

```
bool operator<(const B& b1,const B& b2)
bool B::operator<(const B& b2) const
//recognized by std::sort
```

**Example 2**

```
MyIterator C::begin();
MyIterator begin(C& c);
//recognized by range-based loop
```

As far as I know, those function are **specially** recognized in C++.
(Furthermore, in each pair, they are somehow recognized in the same manner.)

### **Question**

What are the list of all functions that are recognized as **special**?
In other words, is there any part in C++ (official) specification that summarizes the list of them + how special they are?

I believe that if I blindly code without this knowledge, I may make some silly mistake, especially when interact with `std::` class.

Sorry for a not-so-sensible topic name, but I can't think of a better one.

Comment: An old question in SO about operator overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading.
.

Comment: Thank!  That is useful.

Comment: A specification? Sure, do you think C++ just floats in the air? There's a [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/);

Comment: In addition to the operator overload functions, constructors and destructors are special member functions.

Comment: @R Sahu  Thank.  I am also afraid of "begin/end".  Are there any more of them?  The link doesn't mention about it.

Comment: @DeiDei Do you know which part summarizes them in one place?

Comment: No, there isn't such a part. They are scattered all around. As per functions such as begin/end goes, that's about it. Then there's the operator overloading and the special member functions like constructor/destructor which were already mentioned.

Comment: @javaLover, `begin` and `end` are the two other special functions that were essential for the *range-for* implementation (C++11 and later). I don't recall any other special functions.

Comment: @DeiDei Thank for confirmation!   That fact is scary, I don't know when I will step on some bombs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, following are treated specially in C++:

- `main()`, which has more than 1 valid [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6408183/5142350)
- Constructors & Destructors
- Certain special keywords, which are used as of like functions: 4 casts (`static, dynamic, const, reinterpret`) and `typeid`
- `begin()` & `end()` methods or functions are specially treated while dealing with range based `for` loops
- All kind of [overloaded
  operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)
- Conversion operators e.g. `struct A {  operator int (); };`

Few items might be missing. Not sure, if everything is listed somewhere in standard, next to impossible.

However, your fear for messing up with `namespace std` is misplaced. It does contain some standard functions, but unless you don't do `using namespace std`, there is no fear of any messing up.

Comment: Thank for answering my question again!   On topic, I fear that `std::` will sneakily recognize some of my functions when I am not aware.

Comment: @javaLover, that could be either because of `using namespace std` or you might be using header files where certain functions are treated like free functions even though they are supposed to be inside `std`. Are you by chance using deprecated header `<iostream.h>` (`<xyz.h>`) instead of `<iostream>` (or `<xyz>`).

Comment: No.  I never using namespace std.  It is just a fear after I learn about the begin() end().  If I had used that reserved names (begin/end) in my class before I know this fact, it would be a small disaster.

Comment: @javaLover, there are certain other reserve name conventions, which you may find here: [Are identifiers starting with an underscore reserved according to the latest C++ standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12924243/514235) & in its linked duplicate. But in general, C++ is very open language with many paradigms. More you go deeper into this language, more are the chances that you may feel a need to change your current username. ;-) (no offence)

Comment: `swap` is an edge case.